# My servlet stopped receive post params after adding CXF web service to the project

Tags: spring, web-services, jakarta-ee, servlets

Good day, I created simple DynamicWebProject containing servlet Capture extending HttpServlet which overrides method doPost. When I sent a post request to this servlet it successfuly retrieved all posted parameters until I added simple Apache CXF Web Service. The CXF web service works but since I added it my servlet Capture isn't able to receive any posted parameters. When I post data to URL http://x.x.x.x:8080/capture the Capture.doPost method is called but no parameters are passed to it. When I comment out the listener tag it starts work again. Please could you advise why is this happening and how can I fix it? Many thanks in advance. Vojtech

This is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>MyApp</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/cxf.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Capture</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>myapp.servlet.Capture</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Capture</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/capture</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And the cxf.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">
    <jaxws:endpoint id="decodeWS" implementor="myapp.ws.decoder.DecoderServiceImpl" address="/decode">
        <jaxws:features>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature" />
        </jaxws:features>
    </jaxws:endpoint>
 </beans>
```

**EDIT:** I resolved this issue by changing order of servlet mappings. If CaptureParts is on the first place then it works. But I still don't understand why the order matters.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CaptureParts</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/captureParts</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
<param-value>WEB-INF/cfx.xml</param-value>
```

Should it be cxf.xml instead?

Comment: Thank you, I did not notice it, it's a mistype. I fixed it.

Comment: So that wasn't your issue then?

Comment: No it was not my issue, file cfx.xml existed.